# Array 2d loop out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java.

My loop array goes out of bounds. I think my code is all fine.

Can someone help me?

```
String[][] seats = new String[5][3];

for(int r = 1; r <= seats.length; r++){
        System.out.printf(r+ "." );

        for (int c = 1; c <= seats[r].length; c++){
            System.out.print("  0");
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: Index on java, lists, collections,.. starts with 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in java are zero based. So your loop must start at index 0 and the end is lowther than array.length `for(int r = 0; r < seats.length; r++){`

```
String[][] seats = new String[5][3];

for(int r = 0; r < seats.length; r++){
        System.out.printf(r+ "." );

        for (int c = 0; c < seats[r].length; c++){
            System.out.print("  0");
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java array index is 0-based, so it goes from 0 to seats.length-1. Replace <= with < should do

Answer (score 0):

The arrays starts from key 0 and ended at array.length-1

```
String[][] seats = new String[5][3];

for(int r = 0; r < seats.length; r++){
        System.out.printf(r+ "." );

        for (int c = 1; c <= seats[r].length; c++){
            System.out.print("  0");
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
```